# I can't find options for creating mobile services in a locally-installed Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I work in a company where I was requested to create a mobile app and be distributed to our employees only. The requirement is to host the Windows Azure platform locally. I followed this [tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/07/23/step-by-step-installation-of-windows-azure-pack-for-windows-server.aspx), and here is what the portal looks like:

[My Portal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnzZK.jpg)

Based on I've seen in the trial version, there should be a "Mobile Services" tab in there under the Website Clouds, but it isn't there. I searched around but I can't seem to find an answer.

What am I missing here? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Pack features list does not include Mobile Services: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/features.aspx

Comment: Ok. So this does this mean that there is absolutely no way to support a mobile service locally and that we have to subscribe to Microsoft's packages? Or can this option be available for enterprises?

Comment: Azure Stack, the succesor of Azure Pack is to be released tomorrow, wait and see if mobile is in there